Insert from tmp table, with default value
in postgree, assume I have a tmp table, which is the following schema
tmp_data
id   |  name   | ...
--------------------
1    | '1_1'   | ...
null | 'test'  | ...
10   | 'other' | ...

and I have initial table data which has the same schema
id   |  name   | ...
--------------------
1    | '1'     | ...
2    | '2'     | ...

I want to upsert from initial tmp table into final table, and return all ids, so I was thinking to write this query
insert into data (id, name, ...)
select id, name
from tmp_data
on conflict (id) update
set name = excluded.name
returning id

but the problem is that id is auto generated, so - I want to insert the value if it exists (10) and generate if not (null)
I tried to use select case if column null than default - but seems default cant be used in select clause
Splitting query into 2 is not a case for me, as I am using that data in ef core, and I need to do this in 1 batch - and get ids
Result I am expecting
id   |  name   | ...
--------------------
1    | '1_1'   | ...
2    | '2'     | ...
3    | 'test'  | ...
10   | 'other' | ...

Are there any options?

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-merge.html ?

@flackoverstow - tried this - does not work - my guess is the server difference

Next time please mention what version of PG you use

@flackoverstow, yes sir )

If you can't use the merge functionality introduced in PG15, you can also conditionally fetch the next ID value from the sequence when the ID is not already set.
select coalesce(id, nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('public.data','id')))
from temp_data;


Thanks a lot, may be there is a method for default for the column as well? lets say if it is null, take the default value configured in the table (or calculated)

@ArsenMkrtchyan: No I do not think there is such a method, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/vro1UjfJ
